# How to play an audio file with continously updated QBuffer (for audio file) with Phonon?

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, audio-streaming

I’m using Phonon player to play the audio files.

Scenarios:

1. **Files played from local drive** : Plays properly.
2. **Files played from remote drive** : As the audio files are on a USB device I have to keep updating the buffer (QBuffer) and simultaneously play the file. But for some reason the file is not playing in Phonon player. Can anyone please tell me the right way to play the audio file while the buffer is still getting updated?

//Code

```
Phonon::MediaObject* m_pMediaObject = new Phonon::MediaObject(this); 
Phonon::AudioOutput* audioOutput = new Phonon::AudioOutput(Phonon::MusicCategory, this); 
Phonon::Path path = Phonon::createPath(m_pMediaObject, audioOutput); 
QBuffer m_pBufferLoop = new QBuffer(this);
m_pBufferLoop->open(QIODevice::Append || | QIODevice::ReadWrite);
functionToUpdateBuffer();//updates the buffer dynamically.

m_pMediaObject->setCurrentSource(m_pBufferLoop);

m_pMediaObject->play();
```

Nothing happens after I call play(). But if I give the complete buffer then the same code works fine.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using?

Comment: @satuon : The code is across few files so I cannot post it directly. But I can mention what I'm trying to do: 
1. Create a MediaObject (as shown on the test, or by using
::createPlayer) with an empty QBuffer (or not empty, with the 20% of
an Wav/MP3 file).
2. Fill the buffer completely (or the 80% that was missing)
3. play(). Nothing will happen (or 20% of the MP3 will be played).
   It seems it cannot accept streaming data (QBuffer being fed
   dynamically). Any ideas on this ?

Comment: Without seeing the code I can't really know what is wrong with it. But may be somebody else will be able to help.

Comment: @satuon : thanks for replying. I can post few lines of code. Hope this helps:

Phonon::MediaObject* m_pMediaObject = new Phonon::MediaObject(this);
Phonon::AudioOutput *audioOutput = new Phonon::AudioOutput(Phonon::MusicCategory, this);
Phonon::Path path = Phonon::createPath(m_pMediaObject, audioOutput);

QBuffer* m_pBufferLoop = new QBuffer(this);    
m_pBufferLoop->open(QIODevice::Append ||  | QIODevice::ReadWrite);
functionToUpdateBuffer();//updates the buffer dynamically
m_pMediaObject->setCurrentSource(m_pBufferLoop);

m_pMediaObject->play();

Nothing happens after play is called.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code to it instead (with formatting)? It's a bit difficult to read right now.

Comment: `Phonon::AudioOutput audioOutput = new Phonon::AudioOutput` - should be `Phonon::AudioOutput *audioOutput`, I think, i.e. `audioOutput` should be a pointer.

Comment: @satuon : Sorry that is a pointer itself. :) by mistake it's shown like that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21324/discussion-between-satuon-and-dheeraj)

Comment: Phonon itself is not created to handle such behaviour. I remember that I end up with gstreamer and own QGStreamer wrapper around it to handle QBuffer based source.

Comment: @KamilKlimek : can you please explain a little more?

Comment: I've spent a lot of time to make phonon play media from QBuffer like devices. It was realy painful and even when I managed to make it work effects were poor. After switching to GStreamer I managed to achieve same thing a lot faster with less wrapers and abstraction layers between media layer and my code. I can share only my experiences with you because code I wrote is part of bigger solution with closed source.

Comment: @KamilKlimek : thanks for sharing your knowledge. 

Generally how much time will it take to switch to GStreamer?

Comment: I took me about 5 buisness days to migrate whole code from Phonon to GStreamer and write own wrapper around GStreamer. It was whole module logic to rewrite.

Comment: @KamilKlimek : ok. then i have to wait and be satisfied by playing directly without the buffers.